# passing a file identifier string via $_GET method to modify an image src in the target page: solved

Tags: php, image, getmethod

**sending page**

has a link like so,

```html
<a href="http://someurl.org/share?id=<?php echo $ftime;?>" >link to share</a>
```

which produces the correct url form of the GET method by inserting the filemtime() integer that i want to show on the share page, it looks like this on the end of the url

`...share?id=1588888386`

**on the share page**

i'm using $_GET['id'] to define a variable

```php
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

and then inserting that variable into the src of the image file, like so

```html
<img src="test<?php echo $id;?>.jpg">
```

which correctly resolves to

`test1588888386.jpg`

but the image is broken and "Could not load image" according to Firefox even tho that file exists right along side the test.jpg file on the host server... and the base image loads just fine if the 'id' string is NULL.

originally tried using $_GET['id'] directly in the src without going the $id route gives the same results.

i'm at a loss, the only weird clue is FF warning me about "mixed content" with a greyed out padlock.

am i violating some taboo by doing this?

all i want to do is share the version of test.jpg that has that 10digit dynamic number in the file name (the number is extracted from the timestamp when the file is first created).

for now, i'm just manually renaming the file on server, but will eventually use php to copy the test.jpg file and rename it dynamically to add the timestamp, so the test.jpg file can be overwritten the next time it's created by user activity.

Comment: So you're saying `http://someurl.org/test.jpg` works but `http://someurl.org/test1588888386.jpg` does not? If you open the latter directly in your browser, what do you see?

Comment: SOLVED: it seemed that way because i was switching back and forth between two domains to test the code (not something i normally do) and was trying to READ from one folder on the server while WRITING to the other.... never cross the streams!